# How do I specifie pre installation script for debian package with Install4j

Tags: install4j

I will generate an debian package from Install4j. In the GUI we can specify an pre installation script and a post installation script.

The post installation script work fine, but the pre installation script don't work, i.e Install4j don't generate a preinst in the .deb file.

The script I want to use for pre installation script :

```
    #!/bin/sh
    echo "reading additionnal repository"
    IN=${compiler:SOFT_DEPENDENCIES_DEB_32}
    echo $IN

    OIFS=$IFS
    IFS=';'
    arr2=$IN
    for repo in $arr2
    do
        nbRepoPresent=$(egrep -c $repo /etc/apt/sources.list)
        if [ $nbRepoPresent -lt 1 ]; then
        echo "adding additionnal repository $repo"
        sudo add-apt-repository "deb $repo"
        fi
    done
    IFS=$OIFS
```

**Is it a bug or my code is wrong ?**

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the current version (5.0.9). It will be fixed in 5.0.10. You can download the current build here:

http://download.ej-technologies.com/beta/install4j_windows_5_0_10.exe

http://download.ej-technologies.com/beta/install4j_windows-x64_5_0_10.exe

http://download.ej-technologies.com/beta/install4j_unix_5_0_10.tar.gz

http://download.ej-technologies.com/beta/install4j_macos_5_0_10.dmg